# Sql if one column returns null, the whole resultset is null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query:

```
select 'False' as COL_1, coalesce(sum(volume),0) as COL_2 
from table1
where eligible like 'False%' and Month = :month
```

Basically I am creating the first column to read False and what results are found and my problem is that if my col_2 returns null then it still shows the col_1 false in the result.

I want it so that if col_2 returns null, the whole query returns null, I have been playing with coalesce, notnull, ifnull etc.. to no avail.

Any assistance would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Provide some sample data and the expected result from that sample data.

Comment: What is it? MySQL or SQL Server? Please make a decision.

Comment: @Jaques how would that help? COL_1 will always be 'False' and never 'NULL' anyway ...

Comment: Your problem is because you use an aggregate. `COL_2` will never be `NULL`, `COALESCE` will prevent it from being `NULL`

Comment: @Jaques SUM(volume) will be NULL if no rows match the WHERE or all column values summed up are NULL ...

Comment: The `SUM` will be, but `COALESCE` will make sure it is `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (coalesce(sum(volume),0)) IS NULL
            THEN NULL
            ELSE 'False' 
       END AS COL_1, 
       coalesce(sum(volume),0) AS COL_2 
FROM table1 
WHERE eligible LIKE 'False%' AND Month = :month
```

Comment: It might be me and how I read the question, but he wants a NULL query, meaning no results in my world

Comment: Yeah absolutely, this is an alternative in case it is how he wants it outputting.

Comment: And Matt, your case statement will never be `NULL` either `COALESCE` will prevent it

Comment: this proposed solution just has the same output as the original query from the question. I agree with Jaques. Don't understand how this could be the correct answer.

Comment: it `NULL`'s Col1 if Col2 is `NULL` just what he asked for?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT IF(SUM(volume) = 0, NULL, 'False') AS COL_1, SUM(volume) AS COL_2 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'False' as COL_1, sum(volume) as COL_2 
from table1 where eligible like 'False%' and Month = :month  
having sum(volume) is not null
```

sum is an aggregate function. If you want to add a where condition on the aggregated result, you have to define it in the `having` clause part of the select.

The coalesce is no longer necessary as we filter the case where sum(volume)=null.

Comment: Please add a description to your post for the benefit of other readers.